# MySQL table: BIT(1) not null default b'1', however, always default to '0'

Tags: mysql

This is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_spa_cust` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `spa_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `is_valid` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
    `company_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `custno` VARCHAR(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_item_spa_cust_item_spa` (`spa_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_item_spa_cust_item_spa` FOREIGN KEY (`spa_id`) REFERENCES `item_spa` (`id`)) 
;
```

I was expecting the `is_valid` field to default to '1' as I set it, however, it's always defaulting to '0'.

I'm very confused about this, please help.

Comment: It seems to work fine, see demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b14509/1 but you should know that BIT does not print a human-readable '1', it prints a non-printing binary value corresponding to ASCII value 1. You might want to call `HEX(is_valid)`. Or else just use `TINYINT` since you're not really using any less space than 1 byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use `1`, rather than `b'1'`

That being said, in this sqlfiddle, it works as expected.

If you're inserting and looking to default the value, you should NOT SPECIFY it in your insert query.

Answer (score -1):

you should alter your table and modify the default value of the column to 1 instead of b'1' .
this query will do the work :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN column_name BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT 1 ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.